# Laravel - using variables in validator after callback

Tags: validation, laravel

I am using validator callback like this :

```
    $user = DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', '=', $token)->first();

    $validator->after(function($validator){

        if(!$user){
            $validator->errors->add(['user', 'Uživatel pro obnovu hesla nebyl nalezen.']);
        }

        if(!$errors->has() and (time() - $user->time) > 86400){
            $validator->errors->add(['time', 'Od zažádání o resetování hesla uplynulo 24 hodin.']);
        }
    });
```

The $user variable can be setted within callback, but what about $token, which is route parameter. Is there any chance to pass something into the callback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, you use the `use` keyword to pass variables into a callback.

```
$validator->after(function($validator) use ($token)
{
    echo $token;
    if(!$user){
        $validator->errors->add(['user', 'Uživatel pro obnovu hesla nebyl nalezen.']);
    }

    if(!$errors->has() and (time() - $user->time) > 86400){
        $validator->errors->add(['time', 'Od zažádání o resetování hesla uplynulo 24 hodin.']);
    }
});
```